# Как осуществить парссинг flashdeals.aliexpress?

Tags: javascript, java, парсер, jsoup

Стоит задача распарсить flashdeals.aliexpress.
Для меня это абсолютно новая задача, начал я с использования Jsoup. Но результата не получил так как в chrome в инструментах разработчика я вижу:
[image: Инструмент разработчика]
Однако при парсинге с использованием Jsoup я получаю следующий результат:

```html
 <div class="deals-main container"> 
   <div class="deals-container" data-maxtime="6" data-menuid="#pjhvjhr0yep5uab" data-onlypercent="10" data-onlystock="20" data-orderpercent="30" data-orders="50" data-role="deals-container"> 
    <div class="deals-discount-status" data-role="deals-discount-status">
     <span class="status-on status-item active" data-phase="1" data-role="status-item"><span class="status-item-text">NOW</span> </span> <span class="status-up status-item" data-phase="2" data-role="status-item"> <span class="status-item-text">UPCOMING</span> </span>
    </div> 
    <div class="deals-list" data-role="deals-list" data-spm="fdpcl001"></div> 
    <div class="loading" data-role="deals-scroll"></div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```

По гуглив я понял, что информация в deals-list попадает после выполнения скрипта:
Request URL: https://gpsfront.aliexpress.com/getRecommendingResults.do?callback=jQuery183048246769344436435_1615212363465&widget_id=5547572&platform=pc&limit=12&offset=0&phase=1&productIds2Top=&postback=&_=1615212370475

И вот дальше я уперся не пойму в какую сторону рыть...
По сути ты крутишь колесико выполняется скрипт, подгружаются данные. Как мне получить подгруженные данные отправлять на основной сайт эмуляцию скролинга? Но как и какими инструментами не знаю. И даже не уверен даст ли это результат. А если напрямую запускать этот скрипт в программе, то как какие библиотеки использовать? И как правильно строить логику для создания данного скрипта, потому что я так понимаю понадобится куки, возможно какие-то дополнительные переменные...

Буду благодарен если укажите направление в какую сторону искать инфу и в принципе может быть примерный алгоритмы действия для решения такой задачи, на что обратить внимание...
Буду благодарен за любую обратную связь!

Comment: К сожалению, как это делать на Java, я не знаю, но если вы знаете JavaScript и имели дело с Node.js, для вашей задачи хорошо подойдёт https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer — это библиотека, которая управляет скрытым браузером и может автоматически выполнять на загруженной странице большинство действий, доступных пользователю. Подразумевается также, что все скрипты сайта выполняются, и вы можете выполнить любой свой скрипт в контексте документа.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: Можно ли в данном случае сымитировать скроллинг при помощи java.awt.Robot?